# Drop Down List not setting DataValueField

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a drop-down list that contains all of the fields within a table within SQL-Server.  The drop-down list does not fill though and when I use another method of filling it then there's no way I know of setting the DataValueField. Here is my SQL-Server Code for the table

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPORTTEAM
(
supportTeamID int NOT NULL,
supportTeamName varchar(35) NOT NULL,
supportTeamDesc varchar(200) NOT NULL,

Constraint pk_supportTeamID primary key (supportTeamID)

)
```

What I am trying to do is set the `DataValueField` to the `SupportTeamID` and set the `DataTextField` to the `SupportTeamName`.  Here is what I have attempted so far

```
String Sql = @" select * from SUPPORTTEAM";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);          
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
DA.Fill(DS, "SUPPORTTEAM");
DataTable DT = DS.Tables["SUPPORTTEAM"];

DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SupportTeamID";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SupportTeamName";
DropDownList1.DataSource = DT;
```

`DT` has two data rows, but they are not displayed in the drop-down.

I have been looking online for answers and I have not seen a straightforward answer that will do this.  Sorry if this question seems vague, or almost easy to some but is there anything I am missing or needing to change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just an observation but your table is using `supportTeamID` and your code is using `SupportTeamID` (the capital 'S')

Comment: I do not think code is Case Sensitive in Sql but ill try anyway

Comment: What is the type of `cmbSupportTeamID`? I mean ASP/WPF/Winforms?that specific tag is missing

Comment: sorry its a drop down list but I'm very used to Java  Combo Boxes so I just call mine combo boxes but ill change it for the sake of the question

Comment: Does `DT` actually contain any data (try to check `DT.Rows.Count` in debug mode)? Also, are you sure you need the [asp.net] tag here?

Comment: Yeah, I have 2 data rows in that table

Comment: Can you confirm you've changed the casing in the code to match the column name? The .NET code might not be case insensitive...

Comment: I think @defaultlocale is correct, if this was in winforms that would have been a combobox

Comment: @LeeGunn Yeah I tried it, no difference but thanks for the suggestion anyway

Comment: @SpookiBear Have you called `DropDownList1.DataBind` after setting the fields?

Comment: @defaultlocale you're a genius, it works

Comment: @defaultlocale post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`DropDownList.DataBind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd7t67ef.aspx) to actually bind your control to data:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = DT;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is at table filling. Try like this:

```
    String Sql = @" select * from SUPPORTTEAM";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, 
    Properties.Resources.cString);          
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DA.Fill(DS); // change here
    DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0]; // and here

    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SupportTeamID";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SupportTeamName";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = DT;
```

Comment: Everything was working fine, just needed to bind the data.  Thanks anyway!